# Combine 3 columns to one column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, split-apply-combine

I have the following code:

```
input= pd.DataFrame({'Police District Name': ['WHEATON', 'SILVER SPRING', 'BETHESDA','GERMANTOWN','WHEATON','MONTGOMERY VILLAGE'], 
                   'cn1': ['Crime Against Person', 'Crime Against Person', 'Crime Against Person','other','other','other'],
                  'cn2': ['Aggravated Assault', 'bla', 'bla','blaa','bla','one more  bla'],
                   'cn3': ['Aggravated Assault', 'bla', 'bla','blaa','bla','one more  bla'],

                    })
input
```

Desired output:

```
output= pd.DataFrame({'Police District Name': ['WHEATON', 'SILVER SPRING', 'BETHESDA','GERMANTOWN','WHEATON','MONTGOMERY VILLAGE'], 
                       'total crime number':[6,3,3,3,6,3],

                    })
output
```

How can i get this ?.
Thank you!

Comment: where are the values 6,3, etc. coming from?

Comment: @KenDekalb count of crimes in each police district for ex: WHEATON total crimes =6 "cn1 for crime name1 etc"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each value in `cn1`, `cn2` is filled with a crime, you can use the number of columns. The idea is to construct a series of counts via `value_counts` and multiply by the number of `cnx` columns. Then map to your dataframe.

```
counts = df['Police District Name'].value_counts() * (len(df.columns) - 1)
df['total crime number'] = df['Police District Name'].map(counts)

print(df[['Police District Name', 'total crime number']])

  Police District Name  total crime number
0              WHEATON                   6
1        SILVER SPRING                   3
2             BETHESDA                   3
3           GERMANTOWN                   3
4              WHEATON                   6
5   MONTGOMERY VILLAGE                   3
```